# 2008 MINI R56: White smoke coming from turbo after oil leak fix

Tags: leak, mini-cooper, turbocharger

I have a 2008 MINI Cooper S with the JCW package. My turbo oil feed line developed the all-too-common oil leak at the feed line.

I installed the replacement part from Detroit Tuned and reassembled everything correctly (I'll admit that I have a few heat shield screws leftover, but after spending 12 hours on this project, I just wanted to start it up and see if it leaked).

Good news: no oil leaks.

Bad news: Now white smoke that very faintly smells like burning rubber comes out of the turbo area. It's not pouring out, but it's definitely more smoke than the oil leak generated. What did I screw up? Is it just residual brake cleaner burning off (there was oil sprayed everywhere due to the leak)? Is it the turbo cooking itself from lack of oil? I let it idle and revved a few times and everything sounded fine. The top heat shield is hot to the touch after the engine runs for a minute or two.

If it is something bad, is it safe to drive 7-8 miles to a garage or do I need a tow?

Edit: could it be an exhaust leak? As part of the repair I had to take off the down pipe and reattach. I suppose the gasket could have failed there...I'll take off the top heat shield to see if i can tell where the smoke is coming from.

Also, CEL is not on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I took the top heat shield off again tonight and let the engine run for a few minutes. No smoke at all. So it must have been crud on the heat shield burning off.

Bad news is that the return line is still leaking and burning oil. It's off to the shop for now.

Anyone looking to do this job should be prepared for a full day of work and definitely buy a ratcheting 10mm wrench.